# Should I have any readily apparent concerns about the foundation and framing of this new build?

Tags: woodworking, framing, foundation, new-home

**Should I have any readily apparent concerns about the foundation and framing of this new build in the Seattle, WA area? Is there any reason to get an inspection prior to building completion?  I don't suspect anything is wrong, but I don't have a trained eye.**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you suspect an issue?

Comment: No, I don't.  Sorry, I should've been more clear about that.  I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I particularly like the attention to design in the 3rd photo, which shows blocking for the hand rail, and a pocket for the post.

My guess is that you are posting because you are the owner and are acting as the general contractor.  If so, I suggest on a quiet day to bring in your other trades to have a look over before 'signing off' on the framing, as there may be gaps in the blueprints.  Get their feedback on potential issues that they will encounter when they go about their work.  And then discuss those issues with the framers (protecting your sources, that is, I wouldn't say so-and-so said that).  For example, your finish carpenter may want blocking here or there for cabinets, wide casings, etc.  Your landscaper may suggest drainage around the perimeter.  Stuff like that.  So, not compliance issues, but issues that will help the overall project go smoothly.

Comment: A properly trained contractor would not post on a diy website.  More like he's the home owner and just wants peace of mind because he's spending a lot of money on his new home.

Comment: @Matt - Exactly. The OP is not likely a general contractor by profession.  More likely the OP is a home owner that is acting as the general contractor.

Comment: @Matt - Yes, the future home owner and I know we're getting a home inspection when construction is complete.  Just wasn't sure if there were any glaring problems that might deserve an additional inspection.  I wouldn't know, so I thought this site might have some good insight!  Thanks.

Comment: @mike - by general contractor do you mean the person who is managing the whole build and all the contractors?  it's crazy when people do this without any experience.  Ends up costing more IMO

Answer (score 2):

The builder will likely have an inspector, along with the local building authority. If you want a truly independent inspection, you should hire your own inspector.